# What's Kubuntu-Full?

Tags: installation, kubuntu

During text install, it asked me what to install. Along the well known Kubuntu-Desktop and many others, there was Kubuntu-Full. What's it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was curious to know the difference between the two packages so wrote this quick query to see what packages they pull in. This command will show the packages that `kubuntu-full` depends on that `kubuntu-desktop` does not.

```
comm -23 \
    <(apt-cache depends kubuntu-full | awk '/Depends/ {print $2}' | sort -u) \
    <(apt-cache depends kubuntu-desktop | awk '/Depends/ {print $2}' | sort -u)
```

The result at the time of writing (on 12.10) is:

> `anthy`
>   `calligra`
>   `calligra-dev`
>   `dictd`
>   `dict-foldoc`
>   `dict-gcide`
>   `dict-jargon`
>   `dict-moby-thesaurus`
>   `dict-vera`
>   `enscript`
>   `eyed3`
>   `finger`
>   `flac`
>   `kdeaccessibility`
>   `kdeadmin`
>   `kde-baseapps`
>   `kdeedu`
>   `kdegames`
>   `kdegames-card-data-extra`
>   `kdegraphics`
>   `kde-icons-mono`
>   `kdemultimedia`
>   `kdenetwork`
>   `kdepim`
>   `kde-runtime`
>   `kdesdk`
>   `kdeutils`
>   `kde-wallpapers`
>   `kde-workspace-data-extras`
>   `kinfocenter`
>   `konq-plugins`
>   `kubuntu-desktop`
>   `libqscintilla2-designer`
>   `libqt4-sql-odbc`
>   `libqt4-sql-psql`
>   `libqt4-sql-sqlite`
>   `plasma-runners-addons`
>   `plasma-widget-ktorrent`
>   `plasma-widget-lancelot`
>   `pyqt4-dev-tools`
>   `python-qscintilla2`
>   `qt4-demos`
>   `qt4-designer`
>   `qt4-dev-tools`
>   `qt4-doc-html`
>   `scribus`
>   `unclutter`
>   `vorbisgain`
>   `xnest`
>   `xrestop`

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu description for kubuntu-full:

```
Description: Full Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system
 This package depends on all of the packages in the Kubuntu DVD for a very
 complete system.  Installing this package will include much more than the
 default Kubuntu Plasma Desktop or Netbook installation.
```

This includes kubuntu-desktop:

```
Description: Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system
 This package depends on all of the packages in the Kubuntu desktop system.
 Installing this package will include the default Kubuntu Plasma Desktop or
 Netbook installation.
```

Some of collections included in kubuntu-full but not in kubuntu-desktop include: kdeedu, kdegames, kdemultimedia, koffice, kdepim, kdesdk, and qt4-designer.

Comment: What's "much more"?

Answer (score 2):

Both kubuntu and kubuntu-full are "meta" packages, meaning they are a list of packages to be installed. I do not know the exact differences, but it appears -full is targeted at netbooks.

You can see a list of packages here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/kubuntu-full

http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/kubuntu-desktop

kubuntu-desktop is referenced on kubuntu-full, and glancing at the packages I see there is overlap.

Comment: I guess I will not needed it as I'm not installing it on a netbook.

Comment: It's not for netbooks. It's just a lot of KDE applications that are too big to fit on the default CD iso.

Answer (score 0):

kubuntu-full is just a meta-package that includes more software than kubuntu-desktop. Instead of only installing the essential software for a normal user, it installs most of the KDE suite. Another package you can look into is kde-full.

Also, DO NOT install kubuntu-full with a graphical installation. Whenever I install it outside of the terminal, it gets an error while installing one of the language packs. Install it by using `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-full`.